# how do i solve Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, networking, oracle-sqldeveloper, adapter, informatica-powercenter

I restarted services (listener and xe) under services.msc, and stoped and started listener under administrator. And when I open my SQL developer I do not see a NoSQL connection, all I see are two options oracle connection and database schema (and I'm getting the above error). And because of this, I'm unable to install informatica application.

Comment: Are you trying to install Powercenter to use XE as the repository? If you are then I think you will find that XE is unsupported, you need full Oracle product

Comment: how do i install full product. I just followed the installation steps on youtube. can you share any links or information on correct installation

Comment: Go to the Oracle website, download the product and install it?